# How to make statement condition Session in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0 and I want to make if condition in JavaScript.

```
if(Session::get('Role') == '3'){
    $('#add_username').val(Session::get('User_Name'));
}
```

But I have got an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Mixing PHP with JS is an awful idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your script in blade file, you can use this, it should work:

```
if({{Session::get('Role')}} == '3'){
    $('#add_username').val("{{Session::get('User_Name')}}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$value = Session::get('Role');

if($value == '3')
{
     $user_name = Session::get('User_Name');
     $('#add_username').val($user_name);
}
```

Comment: There is an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >` in `$value = $request->session()->get('Role');`

Comment: jQuery and php shouldnt and couldnt be combined like this AFAIK

Comment: We should use `var` instead of `php variable` in `<scrip>`, unless we include `php tag` in `<script> tag and pass it to a `var`, correct me if I am wrong =)